# Compiling Python 3.4 with emscripten on Ubuntu (linkage errors)

Tags: python, build, llvm, emscripten

I am trying to build Python 3.4 from source, using [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten).

I have downloaded and successfully installed emscripten. I have created a build folder outside the source tree. These are the steps I have carried out so far:

1. Run configure:
   `$ emconfigure ../Python-3.4.3/configure --without-threads --without-pymalloc --enable-shared --disable-ipv6 --build=i686-linux-gnu`
2. I noticed that a check for **LONG_BIT** in ../Python-3.4.3/Include/pyport.h conflicts with the `#define SIZEOF_LONG` defined in one of emscriptens headers, so I have commented out the check in ../Python-3.4.3/Include/pyport.h
3. After running configure successfully, I then run `emmmake make` in my build folder
4. I check that the built python file is indeed LLVM bytecode by running `file python`. Having satisfied myself that all is well, I attempt to link the generated libpython3-4.so with the bytecode as follows:

`$ llvm-link libpython3.4.so python -o python.bc`

I get the following error message:

> ERROR: Linking globals named '_Py_open_cloexec_works': symbol multiply
>   defined!

A quick search through the source code shows the symbol is **NOT** multiply defined:

```
$ grep -rnw ../Python-3.4.3 -e "_Py_open_cloexec_works" --include=\*.{c,h}
../Python-3.4.3/Python/fileutils.c:33:int _Py_open_cloexec_works = -1;
../Python-3.4.3/Python/fileutils.c:784:    atomic_flag_works = &_Py_open_cloexec_works;
../Python-3.4.3/Modules/posixmodule.c:7702:extern int _Py_open_cloexec_works;
../Python-3.4.3/Modules/posixmodule.c:7725:    int *atomic_flag_works = &_Py_open_cloexec_works;
../Python-3.4.3/Modules/_io/fileio.c:210:extern int _Py_open_cloexec_works;
../Python-3.4.3/Modules/_io/fileio.c:232:    int *atomic_flag_works = &_Py_open_cloexec_works;
```

So I run `nm` on libpython3.4.so, to check the exported symbols, and I got the following error message:

> nm: libpython3.4.so: File format not recognised

I have run out of ideas now. Can anyone help me solve the linkage issues?

**[[ Additional Info ]]**

- clang version 3.6.0
- LLVM version 3.6.0svn

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `nm`, you can use the powerful `objdump`.  Try `objdump -t you_file`  or `objdump -T you_file`.

Example:  `objdump -t lib.o`

Comment: I just checked the file type for the generated .so file. It turns out its LLVM bitcode, so nm and objdump both do not recognise the file format.

Comment: Try to compile python with g++5 , for me worked perfect.